# Convert Base64 image to raw binary with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, base64, gridfs

I have found posts that are close to what I'm looking for, but I have not been able to successfully implement what I want. Here is the general flow:

1. Submit photo with rest of venue data, as base64 data
2. Strip data prefix if it exists, so I have just the image base64 data

---

```
var base64data = venue.image.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,|^data:image\/jpeg;base64,|^data:image\/jpg;base64,|^data:image\/bmp;base64,/, '');
```

---

3. Store Base64 data in GridFS via MongoDB (I'm using [gridfstore](https://github.com/jupe/gridfstore))
4. Then, I'd like to retrieve the image upon request as a raw image file via a URL.

---

```
// generic images route
server.get(version+'/images/:id', function(req, res) {
  gridfstore.read( req.params.id, function(error,data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
      'Content-Length': data.buffer.length
    });

    res.end(data.buffer);
  });
});
```

Basically, this method returns the Base64 bytes stored in GridFS. I have tried other methods but they don't return the raw image.

I'd like to pull up the image using URLs like this:

```
http://[localhost]/1/images/11dbcef0-257b-11e3-97d7-cbbea10abbcb
```

Here is a screenshot of the browser trace:
[image: browser trace]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can take the string from MongoDB, create a new buffer instance, and specify an encoding when doing so. The resultant buffer will be in binary data.

```
var b64str = /* whatever you fetched from the database */;
var buf = Buffer.from(b64str, 'base64');
```

So in your implementation:

```
server.get(version+'/images/:id', function(req, res) {
  gridfstore.read(req.params.id, function(err, data) {
    var img = Buffer.from(data.buffer, 'base64');

    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
      'Content-Length': img.length
    });
    res.end(img); 

  });
});
```

Comment: thanks @hexacyanide, I tried what you suggested but it is coming back as an invalid image. The buffer is accurately allocated and the length is accurate but the image just doesn't display, so I'll do a little more digging and see if I can provide additional information. When I take the Base64 data URI, and display it in the HTML page with <img src:"[data uri]"> it works, so at least I know the Base64 is valid.

Comment: So what are you trying to do? Are you trying to just display the image on a page?

Comment: I'm trying to simply return the image, just like you would call http://[somehost]/someimage.jpg. I have attached a screenshot if it helps at all. With the code you suggested, the browser just clocks. Also, I am using Restify on the server but from what I have read, it supports Node.js ServerResponse. http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#Content-Negotiation

Comment: and for what it is worth, this is what I see for the data in GridFS. 

"data" : BinData(0,"ZGF0YTppbWFnZS9qcGVnO2Jhc2U2NCwvOWovNEFBUVNrWkpSZ0FCQWdB...

Comment: What do you mean the browser just clocks? Does the `res.end()` fail to work? This doesn't make much sense if embedding the image with HTML works fine.

Comment: I have created 2 gists. One that works, where you'll see I am adding the <img src> tags in the response. So, the buffer still contains Base64 encoded data for the image.

https://gist.github.com/remotevision/6708240

Comment: ARGH!! the image was Base64 encoded when I stored it in GridFS, so it was double-encoded. Now I am storing a single-encoded image and everything is working. whew! thanks for your help

Comment: Works great. Also, don't use a post request to get images in binary. I was going in circles until I realized this.

Comment: How would you specify the name of the file before sending?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your string is correct.  This worked for me..

```
var buf = new Buffer(b64stringhere, 'base64');
var express = require('express'), app = express();
app.get('/img', function(r, s){
    s.end(buf);
})
app.listen(80);
```