# How to read and save base64 image with fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am creating an api node that on the front end (it is separate from the api, I am using fetch to send the data) I am selecting a jpg file and sending in base64 form to the api, I usually receive the base64 in the controller with "var imagem = req.body.imagem; ". I need now to take this base64 and turn it into an image to save in the ../../public/img directory. How could I do that?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Cup = require('../models/Cup');
module.exports = {
    //listagem
    async index(req, res) {
        const cups = await Cup.find();

        return res.json(cups);
    },
    //criaçao
    async store(req, res) {
        var nome = req.body.nome;
        var caminho = req.body.caminho;
        var tema = req.body.tema;
        var imagem = req.body.imagem;
        const cup = await Cup.create({
            nome: nome,
            caminho: caminho,
            tema: tema
        });
        return res.json(cup);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert an image from a base64 representation to its binary representation by converting the string to a `Buffer` - `new Buffer(b64_image, 'base64')` (read more on this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18994979/9155551)). You can then save the buffer to the local filesystem using either [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) (in case you'd like to save the file asynchronously) or [`fs.writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) (in case you'd like to save the file synchronously).

What you're trying to do could be accomplished with something like this:

```js
const fs = require("fs");

const base64Image = "BASE_64_IMAGE";
const imageBuffer = new Buffer(base64Image, "base64");

fs.writeFileSync("image.png", imageBuffer);
```

Comment: I replied with [atob()/btoa()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) (which are great for base64 encoding/decoding "most of the time") ... but your answer is much better :)

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks :) `atob()` could also work well, but when running using Node.js it's usually better to use native `Buffer` objects.

Comment: I got a look and I got to that code: "fs.writeFile ('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', 'utf8', callback);
how and where would I insert my base64?

Comment: @HenriqueRamos In the code you mentioned, `'Hello Node.js'` is the data that's being saved to `message.txt` (and not the image buffer). In your case, the code used to save the file should be along the lines of: `fs.writeFile ('image.png', imageBuffer, callback);`.

Comment: @ItaiSteinherz 
I managed to make a txt file be created, but I still do not understand the buffer well, first that instead of message.txt it has to be correct image.jpg? But regarding base64 and the buffer I did not quite understand

Comment: @HenriqueRamos You have to give the buffer to `fs.writeFile` as the data it should write to the file. I'll add a code example to my answer.

Comment: @ItaiSteinherz
I did the following:
var imagem = req.body.imagem;
const base64Image = imagem;
const imageBuffer = new Buffer (base64Image, "base64");
fs.writeFileSync ('./ public/img/message.jpg', imageBuffer);
but when I try to open the image to visualize this warning appears: there is no support for this file format

Comment: @HenriqueRamos Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43488020/91555510). The issue may be caused by how the given base64 image (`req.body.imagem`) is formatted.

Comment: @ItaiSteinherz
That worked! Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @HenriqueRamos You're welcome :) Feel free to mark my answer as approved ;)